# TextView in customtitle view of alert dialog is not displayed

Tags: android

I make setting customtitle of alertdialog builder with a view that contains two webviews for animated gif and textview between them. the webviews are shown in the title of the alert dialog but the textview is missing.
here the view XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">



    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/Title_webView1"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/titletextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textColor="#d0d2d116"
        android:text="test123"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="32dp" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/Title_webView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

here the view function:

```
private View setCustomDialogTitle(String Title)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.embark_title, null);

    TextView TitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titletextView);
    TitleText.setText(Title);

    WebView flashingLight1 = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title_webView1);
    flashingLight1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/flashlight751.gif");
    WebView flashingLight2 = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title_webView2);
    flashingLight2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/flashlight752.gif");

    return  view;
}
```

and the function call:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alrtBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alrtBuilder.setCustomTitle(setCustomDialogTitle("Test123"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is with setting layout_width for the components and again setting them with weight.

so a small change in xml can help you out.The confusion in rendering will be the cause.

set all the layout_width attribute to "0dp"

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

for the three components, then it will bring you the exact look as you want.  for some reference read [this](http://blog.burakdede.com/how-android-layout_weight-works/) article, it really helps you to understand.

NB: tested and worked for your code

Comment: Thank you this is solved my problem, sory i just cant vote yet.